# Use docker-hub-image in Github actions running on Github-hosted runners

Tags: docker, github-actions

Do the Github-hosted runners support direct use of specific docker images available on docker hub?

For example, using the docker image "aergus/latex" on a self-hosted Gitlab-runner is easy as:

```yaml
job_name:
    image: "aergus/latex"
```

Is it possible to do something similar on Github-hosted runners?
I.e., instead of using "ubuntu-lastest" or "windows-latest", directly specify a docker image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a [job in a container](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) like so:

```yaml
jobs:
  myjob:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container:
      image: node:14.16
    steps:
      - run: uname
```

Note that the runner must be ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I was looking for. On a private runner, commonly used docker images can be cached. Is there a similar option to speed up the step "initialize containers"?